# Can someone please tell me a quick way to deploy a small rails app on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache, deployment, nginx

Yes I know there's not much support for deploying Rails apps in Windows but this is a requirement.  I've searched online for hours looking for a solution to no avail!  I don't need to use any particular server just anyway to get my app viewable on the company intranet.

I installed the WAMR (Windows, Apache, MySQL, Ruby) stack using the BitNami rubystack 1.9.3 installer.  I can see my app using the WEBrick dev server just fine in localhost. I can even see the BitNami Welcome screen (index.html) when pointing to my Windows VM IP address from another computer on the intranet, but I can't figure out how to push the Rails app itself to production so that all other intranet computers can see it.  Any solution would be appreciated!  The server doesn't have to be Apache.

Thanks!

Comment: You can access using IP address of your local machine, or you can give name to your IP address in your local machine just change /etc/hosts file. so that you can access example.com in your intranet only.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way to deploy a rails app on windows?

I would recommend [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to run a linux virtual machine. Install [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) and you'll be able to fully automate the download of the linux image and rails provisioning using tools like [chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/) or [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/).